# Regression Model to Predict

Tags: r, regression, model, linear

I am attempting to create a regression model that would best predict the revenue.

```
Year     GDP_Ind     K_Calls     K_Employees     K_Items     Revenue_USDM
1           100         25           45             11         2000
2           112         27           53             11         2400
3           115         22           54             12         2700
4           123         27           58             14         2900
5           122         32           60             14         3200
6           132         33           65             15         3500
7           143         40           72             16         4000
8           126         30           65             16         4200
9           166         34           85             17         4500
10          157         47           97             18         4700
11          176         33           98             18         4900
12          180         45           100            20         5000

structure(list(Year = 1:12, GDP_Ind = c(100L, 112L, 115L, 123L, 
122L, 132L, 143L, 126L, 166L, 157L, 176L, 180L), K_Calls = c(25L, 
27L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 33L, 40L, 30L, 34L, 47L, 33L, 45L), K_Employees = c(45L, 
53L, 54L, 58L, 60L, 65L, 72L, 65L, 85L, 97L, 98L, 100L), K_Items = c(11L, 
11L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 20L), Revenue_USDM = c(2000L, 
2400L, 2700L, 2900L, 3200L, 3500L, 4000L, 4200L, 4500L, 4700L, 
4900L, 5000L)), .Names = c("Year", "GDP_Ind", "K_Calls", "K_Employees", 
"K_Items", "Revenue_USDM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I believe I would have to use the predict() method to do so but I have tried and can't seem to get it to work and am kind of unsure as to how I would approach it. How would I know that it best predicts the revenue and how would I use it to predict the revenue? Would I have to find the variable most correlated to Revenue and create a regression model for it? I'm just confused.

```
cor(mydata$Revenue_USDM, mydata)
#Linear Regression y~x
mod <- lm(mydata$Revenue_USDM ~ mydata$K_Items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a linear model using all of your variables and then use predict on new data.  As an example,  I will build a model based on the first 11 years and make a prediction for the 12th (which we can compare against the actual value.

```
LM = lm(Revenue_USDM ~ ., data=mydata[1:11,])
predict(LM, newdata=mydata[12,])
      12 
5341.495
```

Comment: The "best model" for predictions would possibly not include all predictors nor would it necessarily be linear.